# How 3rd Quartile (Q3) is positioned at 0.675 SD in case of normally distributed data?

Tags: normal-distribution, standard-deviation

**How was the problem created?**

I was reading [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/966331/why-john-tukey-set-1-5-iqr-to-detect-outliers-instead-of-1-or-2/966337#1935706) of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/966331/why-john-tukey-set-1-5-iqr-to-detect-outliers-instead-of-1-or-2/966337) where the author remarked that

> The 3rd quartile (Q3) is positioned at .675 SD (std deviation, sigma)
>   for a normal distribution.

I understand that Q3 can be positioned at 0.675 SD during normally distribution. However, I really do not understand how it is at 0.675 SD? Why not at 0.775 SD?

**Then, how did I try to find an answer?**

I have searched in Google using different keywords.

[Here](http://www.cs.uni.edu/~campbell/stat/normfact.html), I found that

> It is [readily calculated](http://www.cs.uni.edu/~campbell/stat/normal.html#cut) that for the standard normal distribution the
>   first quartile is -.67 (using .2514 for .25) and the third quartile is
>   .67.  This means that for normally distributed data, one-half of the data is within 2/3 of a standard deviation unit of the mean.

[Here](http://www.users.miamioh.edu/gaddisj/107slides17/05%20-%20Normal%20Curves.pdf), I also found that they have used 0.675 SD to calculate first and third quartile.

I have also checked these questions ([1](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/256456/how-to-calculate-mean-and-sd-from-quartiles), [2](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/17028/how-to-calculate-quartiles-with-only-standard-deviation-and-mean-assuming-normal)) to find the answer. However, still I did not find know how Q3 is positioned at *0.675 SD* in case of normally distributed data?

*Any kind of help will be greatly appreciated.*