# Can the 1.5 be changed when using IQR (interquartile range) method to calculate outliers?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

When calculating outliers using the IQR method, we find a range and define outliers outside of that range (below). Is it 'mathematically' accepted if I change the *1.5* to a *2* to get less outliers for a particular dataset? Or does this break a conventional theory?

Additionally, does the data need to follow a normal distribution to use this method?

- IQR: Q3 – Q1
- Upper bound: Q3 + (1.5 * IQR).
- Lower bound: Q3 – (1.5 *
  IQR)
- Outlier = outside of range [Lower, Upper]

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/966331/why-john-tukey-set-1-5-iqr-to-detect-outliers-instead-of-1-or-2

Comment: Thanks for sharing @JukkaKohonen! If the data is right skewed, can I adjust the 1.5 to 2? (as in, it's not a perfectly centered bell curve).

Comment: The top answer in the linked question does say that 'goldilocks' would choose 1.5 but would it 'break' any mathematical theory if I make it 2?

Comment: There is no "outlier/not outlier" threshold. It is all a question of extremity.  Some points are more extreme than others, in terms of distance from the main body of the data; such points have a greater degree of "outlierness," if you will. A z-score, or similar statistic using medians and IQRs, will suffice as a degree of "outlierness."  In multiple dimensions, Mahalanobis distance and its variants serve the same purpose.  There really is not much point to trying to create a "Yes/No" condition for outliers.

Comment: Thanks @BigBendRegion! I don't seem to have an 'upvote' button, but this is good!

Comment: Ok, I made it a bona fide answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "outlier/not outlier" threshold. It is all a question of extremity. Some points are more extreme than others, in terms of distance from the main body of the data; such points have a greater degree of "outlierness," if you will. A z-score, or similar statistic using medians and IQRs, will suffice as a degree of "outlierness." In multiple dimensions, Mahalanobis distance and its variants serve the same purpose. There really is not much point to trying to create a "Yes/No" condition for outliers.

Comment: When using this method, do we assume the data follows a gaussian distribution?

Comment: No, definitely not.